# Mule Multiple flows loading shared properties file

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a mule application comprising of 10 mule XML files. Some of these XML files need to use same property from commong prperties (config.properties) file.

(1) Should ALL the flows that need use a given property load the properties file containing that property using --

```
<context:property-placeholder location="config.properties" />
```

(2) OR should only one of the XML file add property-placeholder?

(3) If option (2) is right, then does the order of mentioning the xml files as config.resources in mule-deploy.properties play any role?

Please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3):

You only need it once, and it does not matter where you put it.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one property file and you can setup this for 3 environments liks DEV,QA and PROD and setop property to pick right file.

Answer (score -1):

There is a lot of documentation that shows users different ways to read a properties file in Mule flows.
 Here are three approaches on how you can do this:

```
Reading a properties file using ${Key} expression
Reading a properties file using ![p[‘Key’]] expression
Reading a properties file using p() function from DataWeave
```

If you deploy multiple applications through a Shared Resources structure, don’t set anything in the properties files, as there might potentially be conflicts between the various apps that share a domain. Instead, set environment variables over the scope of the deployed app, its domain, and other apps under that domain.

As explained in Shared Resources, in Studio you can create these variables through the Environment tab of the Run Configurations menu, reachable via the drop-down menu next to the Play button.